# Error 403 Don't have permission to access on this server

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

Can someone please help, my website is runing at www.mysite.com and i wan't to add /demo, so a whole url would be www.mysite.com/demo. Site is running from `/var/www/html`. I created new folder `/var/www/html/demo` where i have `index.html`. But when i navigate to www.mysite.com/demo i get

> error 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /demo on this
>   server

. I have searched answers and tried to change `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>     
</VirtualHost>
```

and made `sudo service apache2 restart` but still get the same error.I am running Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server. Can someone please tell what and where should i change...Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure apache has permission to access the files. 
If the apache user is www-data you can set it as owner with chown:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/demo
```